# Load balancer with PHP include, can I include the file from only server A

Tags: php, load-balancing

If I'm using a load balancer with 2 droplets on Digital Ocean.

I want to use a PHP include for an HTML file.

is there anyway to only include the file from server A, not server B?

The use case is that these html files are generated by my customer, and will be written to a single server.

Comment: there is no single load balancer, there is no single way to install\use a load balancer. this question lacks a lot of basic detail

Comment: What more detail would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an `if` statement:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "servera.yourdomain.com") {
    include("file.html");
} else {
    include("http://servera.yourdomain.com/path/to/file.html");
}
```

Note that this will only work for static files like HTML. If you try to include a PHP file through the webserver, it will be executed on the remote server instead of returning the source code.

Comment: Right, that's actually what I'm referring to. I want them to be able to access file from server A even if they're on server B.

Comment: Since it's on a load balancer, wouldn't i need to use the ip address or something? Both servers would be using the same domain.

Comment: `www.yourdomain.com` should point to the load balancer IP, but `servera.yourdomain.com` and `serverb.yourdomain.com` should point to the individual server IPs.